# Indirect variable/parameter reference (name in another property / another variable)

Tags: xslt

Is it possible using XSL to access a variable (or a parameter) whose name is stored in another variable (or parameter)? If no, why?

I am new to xsl, coming from other languages, where this functionality is accessible, like bash, ant. Maybe I was wrong even looking for an answer to this question. But since I didn't find it on SO, I think there should be one.

Two examples. I have parameters `p1`, `p2`, `p3`. Then I have a parameter `pname` whose value is a string `p2`. I would like to read the value of `p2` using `pname`, something like `$$pname` or `${$pname}`. Or in a more complicated way. If `pnumber` is equal to `2`, then I would like to read the value of the parameter with name `concat('p', $pnumber)`, something I would code as
`param-value(concat('p', $pnumber))`.

Comment: The languages you refer to - bash, ant - are macro-based languages where nearly everything happens at run-time. XSLT isn't like that; it's much more like compiler-based languages (C/Java etc) where variable and function names are purely compile-time constructs.

Comment: @Michael, don't you think it could be an answer to this question? Who may give a better answer for "why" than you? :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is possible whenthe XSLT stylesheet accesses itself as a regular XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="p1" select="'P1-Value'"/>
 <xsl:param name="p2" select="'P2-Value'"/>
 <xsl:param name="p3" select="'P3-Value'"/>

 <xsl:param name="pName" select="'p3'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pNumber" select="2"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('Param with name ',
             $pName,
             ' has value: ',
             $vDoc/*/xsl:param[@name = $pName]/@select
             )"/>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>   

   <xsl:variable name="vParam" select=
      "$vDoc/*/xsl:param[@name = concat('p', $pNumber)]"/>

     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat('Param with name p',
             $pNumber,
             ' has value: ',
             $vParam/@select
             )"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
Param with name p3 has value: 'P3-Value'
Param with name p2 has value: 'P2-Value'
```

**Explanation**:

The expression `document('')` selects the document node of the current XSLT stylesheet.

A limitation is that the current XSLT stylesheet must have (be accessible via) a URI (such as residing at a given file and accessible by its filename) -- the above code doesn't produce a correct result if the stylesheet is dynamically generated (a string in memory).

Comment: This is a solution for parameters, however limited to parameters whose value is not set from outside (command line, `addParameter`), right?

Comment: @Jarekczek: Correct. Parameter's dynamic value cannot be accessed in this way. There is no such thing as reflection in XSLT -- although using the above technique one can discover at run-time parameter and variables names, it isn't possible to find their dynamically assigned values -- and one reason for this is that in a functional language there is no notion of time -- when our code is executing there is no guarantee some particular code fragment (which assigned the value to the parameter) has already been executed.

Answer (score 0):

**A portable workaround**. If you control both the application and the stylesheet, you should **pass the parameters as an xml document**. Most processors give the option to make parameter a node-set. For example in MSXML I did it using:

```
xslProc.addParameter("params", xmlParams)
```

where `xslProc` is of processor type, created from `"Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0"` using `createProcessor` method and `xmlParams` is `DomDocument`. Inside the stylesheet I was accesing my parameters using something like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="value">
  <xsl:value-of select="$params//*[name() = concat('p', $pnumber)]" />
</xsl:variable>
```

If the processor does not support node-set external parameters, one may always combine the parameters with the data in one xml document. This works well in memory. If access to external files is possible, one may use `document('params.xml')` syntax to access the parameters stored in a separate file.

I was also looking for a possibility to parse xml string and have a node-set of it, but it is seems to be available only as an extension in some xslt 2.0 parsers. I wanted 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `libxslt` the thing is possible through **`dyn:evaluate` extension**. Here is [the description](http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html). There is total of 3 processors mentioned which are said to support this function:

- Xalan-J from Apache (version 2.4.1) and
- 4XSLT, from 4Suite. (version 0.12.0a3)
- libxslt from Daniel Veillard et al. (version 1.0.19)