# Variable into variable in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have any param

```
<xsl:param name='param_1'/>
<xsl:param name='param_2'/>
...
<xsl:param name='param_100'/>
```

and any templates for items with id='1', id='2' ... id='100'

```
<xsl:template match='item[@id="1"]'>
   <xsl:value-of select='$param_1'/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='item[@id="2"]'>
   <xsl:value-of select='$param_1'/>
</xsl:template>
...
...
<xsl:template match='item[@id="100"]'>
   <xsl:value-of select='$param_100'/>
</xsl:template>
```

How to combine items into a single template?

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match='item[@id="1" or @id="2" or @id="100"]'>
   <xsl:variable name='id' select='@id'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='$param_$id'/>
</xsl:template>
```

xsl:choose not good, items and params very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indirect variable/parameter reference (name in another property / another variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207477/indirect-variable-parameter-reference-name-in-another-property-another-variab)

Comment: Yes, but this don't worked if my param is dynamic: <xsl:param name="param_1" select="$variable_1"/>. At the output I get "$variable_1"

Comment: This is not how you are supposed to do it. Please see the actual link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in 100 parameters, pass in a single parameter with internal structure:

```
<params>
  <param nr="1" value="x"/>
  <param nr="2" value="y"/>
  ..
</params>
```

Then it's simply

```
<xsl:template match="item[@id >= 1 and 100 >= @id]">
  <xsl:value-of select="$params//param[@nr=current()/@id]"/>
</xsl:template>
```